Alternating rows background - updating dynamically when hiding/showing rows with css only?
I have a table ".report" and it should have alternating background for its rows. The UI allows users to hide and show rows dynamically and I want the background of the rows to keep the pattern at all times. I implemented the solution where I add the ".hidden" class to the hidden rows and set the background-color attr to shown rows only and then set the background to "nth-of-type" accordingly. But it doesn't work. It seen the nth-of-type doesn't take the ":not(.hidden)" rule into consideration. Is it possible to resolve this with CSS only? I know I can change the background with JS but I'd rather avoid it and use css only if possible.
restoreRow: function(key) {
    let row = $("#" + key);
    row.show();
    row.removeClass("hidden");
},

removeRow: function(key) {
    let row = $("#" + key)
    row.hide();
    row.addClass("hidden");
},

.report tbody tr:not(.hidden):nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: $white;
}

.report tbody tr:not(.hidden):nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: red;
}


Yes, with the new nth-child(n-of-x) selector
tr:nth-child(odd of :not(.hidden)) {
  background: lightgreen;
}

tr:nth-child(even of :not(.hidden)) {
  background: lightblue;
}



table {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

tr:nth-child(odd of :not(.hidden)) {
  background: lightgreen;
}

tr:nth-child(even of :not(.hidden)) {
  background: lightblue;
}
<p>No rows hidden</p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td>Item 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td>Item 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td>Item 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td>Item 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>2nd row is hidden</p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td>Item 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hidden">
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td>Item 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td>Item 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td>Item 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>




I don't think there is a only-css solution to do that, you need to consider the JS
refreshRowStyles do the style for all the tr that doesn't have hidden class.
function refreshRowStyles() {
    $('.report tbody tr').not('.hidden').each(function(index) {
        if (index % 2 === 0) {
            $(this).css('background-color', '$white');
        } else {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    });
}

Call this method when the DOM initialized.
$(document).ready(function() {
    refreshRowStyles();
});

Also, you need to call it with restoreRow and removeRow methods to ensure the styles are updated every time a row's visibility is changed.
restoreRow: function(key) {
    let row = $("#" + key);
    row.show();
    row.removeClass("hidden");
    refreshRowStyles();
},

removeRow: function(key) {
    let row = $("#" + key);
    row.hide();
    row.addClass("hidden");
    refreshRowStyles();
},

